# Is a 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo better than a 2.0GHz dual-core Intel Core i5 with turbo Boost up to 3.1GHz?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, performance

I think my 2008 Macbook is about to bite the dust and wanted to buy a new Macbook Pro.....I noticed that I have the option to purchase a 2.0GHz processor which has a 3.1GHz "turbo boost".  Would the turbo boost make this a better/faster processor?  I will be using the Macbook mainly to run Logic Pro along with music plugins.

Comment: regarding Logic Pro making use of Turbo Boost: https://www.logicprohelp.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=127837

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't be fooled by the Ghz. The i5-6360U is in the [Late 2016](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.0-13-late-2016-retina-display-no-touch-bar-specs.html) 13" MacBook Pro and is a Skylake CPU. I assume your [2008 MacBook Pro](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.4-15-early-2008-penryn-specs.html) is a 15" model, as the 13" did not ship with that CPU.

The newer i5 machine has a Geekbench score of 3609 vs 1320 for the Late 2008 MacBook Pro 15".

Not only that, but the newer Mac features better graphics (even integrated graphics), built in SSD, etc. If  you still have a hard drive in your old Mac, the SSD alone will shock you in performance improvements for your Mac.

[GeekBench](https://browser.primatelabs.com/mac-benchmarks)

Update: I see some additional questions in the comments about how a 2 Ghz processor can 'beat' a 2.4 Ghz processor. One thing to note is that the transition at Intel from Pentium to Core Duo essentially ended the Ghz wars. Intel found the adding cores, reducing heat and improving cacheing improved performance more than Ghz. This really showed when their mobile CPUs were beating out their desktop CPUs, so Intel switched to their 'mobile architecture' for everything, thus Core and Core Duo.  The i Series are built on that philosophy.

Another way to look at it is this: Most common car (US) V8 engines in the  70s produced as little as 110 HP. (Muscle cars made much more, but enlarged the engine and got terrible gas mileage) Today, we have 4 cylinder engines that produce 300 HP, and V8s that produce muscle car HP but get economy car fuel mileage. So, how does a 4 cylinder make more horsepower than a V8?  Its far more than the number of cylinders, just as its is far more than Ghz for CPUs.

Comment: So basically your saying that the all over improvements will make the 0.4 GHz difference unrecognizable?

Comment: @Nick Yes. Infact the i5 2.0 GHz processor would theoretically, be 3 times faster than the 2008 macbook.

Comment: @Rio That's really interesting..Could you please explain why that is?

Comment: @Nick same reason the 2 GHz CPU in your phone isn't as fast as the one in this laptop, or how a small child won't outrun an adult even if taking twice as many steps - frequencly is only part of the equation.

Comment: @tolgraven but what I'm trying to understand is what is the difference?

Comment: The i5 has tricks for doing more each clock cycle.   Intel would love to tell you all about it: <http://ark.intel.com/products/91156/Intel-Core-i5-6360U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz>